# Check if decimal values are in a range in R

Tags: r

I need to re-categorize codes that represent various diseases so as to form appropriate groups for later analysis.

Many of the groupings include ranges that look like this:

```
1.0 to 1.5, 1.8 to 2.5, 3.0
```

where another might be `37.0`

Originally I thought that something like this might work:

```
x <-c(0:.9, 1.9:2.9, 7.9:8.9, 4.0:4.9, 3:3.9, 5:5.9, 6:6.9, 11:11.9, 9:9.9, 10:10.9, 12.9, 13:13.9, 14,14.2, 14.8)

df$disease_cat[df$site_code %in% x] <- "disease a"
```

The problem is, `0.1,0.2` etc. are not being recognized as being in the range of `0:0.9`.

I now understand that `5:10` (for example) in r is actually `5,6,7...10`

What is a better way to code these intervals so that the decimals will be recognized as being in the interval `0` to `0.9`? (keeping in mind that there will be many "mini" ranges and the idea of coding them all explicitly isn't particularly appealing)

Comment: These first 2 answers work in this case but what I failed to have specified more clearly is I am interested in creating a list of different ranges for the purposes of re-coding a number of different values which include decimals. Is there a more efficient way of finding if values are in a range (including decimals)?

Comment: @Jacob Please edit your question and specify what exactly you need.

Comment: I suppose that there may not be another way to define them, so I think I will go about it like this:  c(seq(0,.9,by = .1), (seq(5.6,5.9,by = .1)) etc. unless someone thinks there is a better way

Comment: @Jacob Is there any chance that two intervals have a common point?

Comment: There shouldn't be, no

Comment: @Jacob `seq()` is the way to go, `x:y` is the equivalent of `seq(x, y, by=1)`, there is no way to specify a `by` argument in `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer by printing the content of `c(1.1:4)`. The result is `[1] 1.1 2.1 3.1`. The thing you need is `findInterval` function. Check out this solution:

`findInterval(c(1,2,3,4.5), c(1.1,4)) == 1`

If you would like to have the inclusive right boundary, i. e. [1.1, 4] interval, you can use `rightmost.closed` parameter:

`findInterval(c(1,2,3,4.5), c(1.1,4), rightmost.closed = TRUE) == 1`

EDIT:

Here is the solution for a more general problem you have described:

```
d = data.frame(disease = c('d1', 'd2', 'd3'), minValue = c(0.3, 1.2, 2.2), maxValue = c(0.6, 1.9, 2.5))
measurements = c(0.1, 0.5, 2.2, 0.3, 2.7)

findDiagnosis <- function(data, measurement) {
  diagnosis = data[data$minValue <= measurement & measurement <= data$maxValue,]
  if (nrow(diagnosis) == 0) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(diagnosis$disease)
  }
}

sapply(measurements, findDiagnosis, data = d)
```

Comment: Thanks Ardavel, I changed me question to better reflect what I'm looking for

Comment: @Jacob I've just updated my answer to help solving the extended problem.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought about  doing it that way, Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy it works for you. Please accept the answer if you find it most helpful ;)

Comment: I tried accepting it by upvoting the answer, however is there something else that I do to accept it?

Comment: @Jacob There should be a check mark visible for you on the left of the post :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
c(1,2,3,4.5) >= 1.1 & c(1,2,3,4.5) <= 4
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Examine the output of `1.1:4`:

```
1.1:4
[1] 1.1 2.1 3.1
```

You are actually testing whether elements from your vector are *exactly equal to* 1.1, 2.1, or 3.1

Answer (score 1):

```
#This the list of your ranges that you want to check
ranges = list(c(0,.9), c(1.9,2.9), c(7.9,8.9), c(4.0,4.9), c(3,3.9), c(5,5.9), c(6,6.9), c(11,11.9), c(9,9.9), c(10,10.9), c(12.9), c(13,13.9), c(14),c(14.2), c(14.8))

#This is the values that you want to check for each range in ranges
values = c(1,2,3,4.5)

#You can check each value in each range with following command
output = data.frame(t(sapply(ranges, function(x) (min(x)<values & max(x)>values))))

#Maybe set column names to values so you know clearly what you are checking.
#Column names are values, row names are indexes of the ranges
colnames(output) = values
output$ranges = sapply(ranges, function(x) paste(x,collapse = "-"))
```